# Is there any module which list the related nodes based on the title , So that the user can set multiple related node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Is there any module which list the related nodes based on the title , So that the user can set multiple related node.

i want to display related songs based on title without using taxonomy.

like http://www.djcity.com/digital/robin-thicke-give-it-2-u-viol8tor-trap-remix---32213.htm

any body help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its the best module: https://drupal.org/project/featured_content

But if you want more alternatives, visit this url: https://groups.drupal.org/node/12347

I hope the information has been useful.

Regards.